# Multiple URLs for the same page on scroll. Is it SEO frendly?

Tags: seo, html5

I have a web page with some sections, and I made the url change (with the html5 history api) when I scroll to these sections.
Is it SEO frendly?
Won't Google see my page as multiple pages instead of just one (it's not what I want)?

I know that it's ok to do these kind of thing with infinite scroll but it's not my case. The url changes by scrolling into diferent sections of my page.

Here is the example:
http://litoralverde.com.br/destinos/angra-dos-reis-G6667

Is it ok?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the URL change? Is it a query string, or a hashbang? If you're dynamically changing something you have to tell Google how it is you're doing it. Otherwise it'll be unable to index your site and you may have to pre-render it with a product like prerender.io

Comment: Presumably these URLs are navigable? Are you also including these URLs in your sitemap? I don't see why you differentiate here between infinite / finite scrolling? If you think it's OK for infinite scrolling pages then why not here?

Comment: What happens when a user links to one of these URLs?   Does your page still load with the correct content?     Why wouldn't you want Google to think you have multiple pages?   A single large page rarely performs as well in search as multiple pages that are easy for Google to deep link to.  Do you link to these URLs anywhere, or are they only revealed through scrolling?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details as requested by Yharian, w3dk, and myself.

Comment: I have put a link to the page.

Comment: I don't have links to the specific sections of the page anywhere. The URLs are only revealed when the user scrolls down the page.